# Index page from React Router Dom not showing in Django

Tags: reactjs, django, react-router, django-urls

I have 2 different apps `Landing` and `Main`. Both use react build files as templates and static files to render information on the web page. This works fine for the `Landing` app but not the `Main` app, which is probably because despite both using React Router Dom, the routes on the `Main` app redirect the user to /boards instead of having an index page - so the path is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/[username]/boards` instead of just `http://127.0.0.1:8000/[username]`. Instead of being redirected to the correct page, all that is shown is a blank page.

I already tested this to see if something would be shown on the webpage if there was an index page and there is. The `Landing` app's routes does have an index page and this works fine.
I also tried adding this re_path `re_path(r".*")` but this doesn't work either.
Everything works fine when I run  the React app by itself in the browser (with npm run dev and vite) but not when I run it in the browser with Django (python manage.py runserver). A console.log made in the main javascript file in the React App is shown in the console but there is still a blank page.

How do I fix this?

`Main` urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.index, name='index'), 
    re_path(r".*", views.index, name='index') # does not work
]
```

`Main` App.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Boards from "./pages/board/Boards";

export default function App() {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route
                        path="/"
                        element={<Layout setCurrent={setCurrent} />}
                    >
                        <Route index element={<Navigate to="/boards" />} />
                        <Route path="boards" element={<Boards />} />
                        ...
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}
```

Layout.jsx

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Layout({ setCurrent }) {
    return (
        <div className="body-container">
            <header className="page">
                ...
            </header>
            <div className="main-container">
                <Outlet />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./styles/styles.css";

export const getDatabaseData = async model => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${model}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(model, "data:", data);
    return data;
};
getDatabaseData("current-user");

export const createWorkspace = async formInfo => {
    fetch("/api/workspaces", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: {
            name: formInfo.name,
            description: formInfo.description,
            creator: formInfo.user,
            members: formInfo.members,
        },
    });
};

export const logout = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("/logout", {
        method: "post",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        // body: {},
    });
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<str:username>/', include(('main.urls', 'main'), namespace='main')),
]
```

`Landing` views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main:index", args={request.user.username}))
    else:    
        return render(request, "index.html")
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a dumb question, but do you render the `App` component anywhere with `ReactDOM`?

Comment: Is `Layout` rendering an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their `element` content out on? Can you [edit] to include all the relevant UI code you are working with so we can check/ensure that is setup properly? (*e.g. from root to routed component, the entire ReactTree*) See [mcve].

Comment: @mkkekkonen Yes I do. It is rendered though the #root element.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the code for `Layout.jsx`. I also used an `Outlet` so everything should work fine.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the UI code so the issue probably is with the server configuration. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No I don't see any errors. However, I do see a console.log made in the index javascript file.